# Select query causing exception

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, function

When does the below sql function can cause an exception other than NO DATA FOUND?
v_ExchangeRate is of type float.The datatype of rate column is NUMBER(14, 10) and this column can not contain NULL values.

```
BEGIN
SELECT rate
INTO v_ExchangeRate
FROM exchange_rate
WHERE currency_code = CurrencyCode
AND status        = 'A';
```

The data type of exchange_rate in database is NUMBER(14,10)

**Edit**
Multiple rows cannot be returned by the where clause as the currency_code is the primary key.

Comment: what exception? what type of dbms? mysql/sql server/oracle?

Comment: Assuming RDBMS is Oracle. If you do not have a constraint such that currency_code with Status = 'A' is unique, you may get a too many rows exception. (Exact name escapes me.)

Comment: Other than NO DATA FOUND exception , I am using proC with oracle database

Comment: @Shannon , two many rows is not the case here, I am sure that only one row will exist

Comment: So, are you getting exceptions and don't know what they are? Or just want to konw what exceptions are possible?

Comment: I am getting exceptions but dont know what they are

Comment: Then why don't you post the exception message?

Comment: I dont know what is the exception? I only know it is other than NO ROWS FOUND

Comment: How do you know it's not NO_DATA_FOUND? How do you know any exception is being raised at all (if your WHEN OTHERS handler swallows all exceptions without doing anything, how do you know it is actually being executed anyway)? How do you know the query is not being executed?
There are many exceptions that might be raised - e.g. data type conversion exceptions, object security violations, PL/SQL exceptions (e.g. no RETURN executed, for example)...

Comment: Too many questions, when I am getting a NO DATA FOUND return value will be 1 and when its OTHER the return value would be 2. I am getting 2 from the function hence I am pretty sure about the exception returned is OTHER THAN NO DATA FOUND

Comment: Any reason for downvoting this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible exceptions (not an exhaustive list by any means):

1) ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

```
declare
  var integer;
begin
  select 1 into var from nosuchtable;
end;
```

2) ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error

```
declare
  var integer;
begin
  select 'x' into var from dual;
end;
```

3) ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

```
declare
  var varchar2(1);
begin
  select 'xx' into var from dual;
end;
```

4) ORA-01722: invalid number

```
SQL> create table t1 (n1 number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into t1 values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> declare
  2    var varchar2(1);
  3  begin
  4    select 'x' into var
  5    from t1 where n1 = 'y';
  6  end;
  7  /
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-0512: at line 4
```

Can you not create a **copy** of the function, remove the WHEN OTHERS part, and test it in SQL Plus or an IDE to see what exception you get?

Answer (score 2):

What problem are you trying to solve here, or is this just a theoretical question? If an exception is being raised and you are suppressing it with a WHEN OTHERS clause then remove that clause -- it's presence is a coding error (ie. a bug).

Comment: I can not modify the code as it is used by an online system, I just know by reviewing the code that the exception caused is other than NO ROWS FOUND

Comment: So you do have a WHEN OTHERS clause that is suppressing an error?

Comment: Yes I do have a WHEN OTHERS clause

Answer (score 1):

Doing an SQL trace MAY show the exception (if it raised by SQL rather than the PL/SQL).

Alternatively [DBMS_TRACE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96612/d_trace.htm#1000315) has the ability to record exceptions even when they are caught by an exception handler. But you'd have to install the supporting tables.

```
D:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\RDBMS\ADMIN>sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production on Mon Dec 14 09:24:45 2009
Copyright (c) 1982, 2005, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connected to:
Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Release 10.2.0.1.0 - Production
SQL> @tracetab.sql
SQL> CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM plsql_trace_runs FOR plsql_trace_runs;
SQL> CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM plsql_trace_events FOR plsql_trace_events;
SQL> CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM plsql_trace_runnumber FOR plsql_trace_runnumber;
SQL> GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON plsql_trace_runs TO PUBLIC;
SQL> GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON plsql_trace_events TO PUBLIC;
SQL> GRANT SELECT ON plsql_trace_runnumber TO PUBLIC;
```

Now for a demo :

```
create or replace
procedure test_trace is
  v_test varchar2(3);
begin
  select '12' into v_test from dual;
  select '123' into v_test from dual;
  select '1234' into v_test from dual;
  select '12345' into v_test from dual;
exception
  when value_error then
    null;
end;
/
```

Run the test by clearing out the table of any old junk, set the flag and execute the procedure

```
delete from plsql_trace_events;
commit;
exec DBMS_TRACE.set_plsql_trace (DBMS_TRACE.trace_all_exceptions);
exec test_trace;
```

Then query the results.

```
select event_kind, event_unit, event_line, stack_depth, excp, event_comment, callstack, errorstack
from plsql_trace_events
where event_kind not in (38,40,43,44)
order by event_seq;

 EVENT_KIND EVENT_UNIT                       EVENT_LINE STACK_DEPTH        EXCP
----------- ------------------------------- ----------- ----------- -----------
EVENT_COMMENT
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CALLSTACK
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERRORSTACK
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      52.00 TEST_TRACE                             6.00        2.00    6,502.00
Exception raised
----- PL/SQL Call Stack -----
  object      line  object
  handle    number  name
3BF0F6D4         6  procedure GARY.TEST_TRACE
3BDF1764         1  anonymous block
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

      53.00 TEST_TRACE                            11.00        2.00    6,502.00
Exception handled
```

We can see an exception was raised at line 6 and the fact that it was caught at line 11. The latter is pretty important too. If you have some complex code, it isn't impossible that an exception handler a couple of levels up the call hierachy may 'handle' an exception for which it was never intended. You can even see the error number which is handy if it got caught by a WHEN OTHERS.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm a little lost, but what is CurrencyCode? I'm guessing `exchange_rate` and ExchangeRate are tables in your database? It's confusing to have a column and a table named `exchange_rate`, unless that's part of the problem.

Comment: To avoid the confusion, I have renamed exchange_rate to rate, Now rate is the column and exchange_rate is the name of table.I am fetching rate column in exchangerate variable with the help of primart key so always a single row would be returned

Answer (score 0):

Paste your Full stored procedure, its really confusing exchange_rate table or column and currency code also. I feel same variable used  for column id and table name gives exception

Comment: Lets check it once, I have added v_ in front of variable name